# Resource usage of docker with no containers running?

Tags: docker, battery-life

Long ago, I needed to install Docker for a college class. I still have it installed, but I haven't run anything on it for quite a while now.

Does it still consume CPU/RAM/etc -- anything that would reduce battery life of the laptop it lives on -- or is it fine to leave there? (The hard disk space usage is fine.)

I haven't deleted it yet because I may want to tinker with the program in the container, and I don't want (or remember how) to reinstall it. Is this costing me runtime of my computer on battery mode?

If it is a problem, how do I securely uninstall both Docker and the container (wherever Docker actually puts these things)? I run stock Ubuntu 18.04, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Docker resource usage depends on your settings.

You can easily verify if docker processes use any CPU, and if not then you have none
of these settings and can leave it installed.
If you see them using any resources, you will have to track down the involved
settings.

You may see some of these possible settings listed in the docker bug report
[Windows 10 Docker processes consuming high CPU with no running containers](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1772).